# Error in apache configuration

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin, perl, cgi

Initially my PHP was running well and after that when I installed perl CGI modules in order to run my CGI programs, there was problem.

From the local host, I am not able to compile my PhP files nor my CGI files, I have tried all sort of possible solutions available in the google and finally wriring here.

I have tried to restart the apache2 and here is the syntax error I could find.

```
Syntax error on line 151 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command '/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Kindly give me a possible solution to run both my CGI and PHP scripts.?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you're including the right file: `etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

If you used `apt-get install phpmyadmin`, you don't need to reference the `apache.conf` file, it is automatically configured.

Take a look at this post too:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: I have tried the same in the given link...But it still gives the same error when i restart the apache

Comment: try using include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf. confirm that the file exists in the location specified

Comment: My PhP scripts were working well but still i am facing problem in executing the CGI scripts. In /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf, the configuration was ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"   ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"    and removed "#" from  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi in order to enable the execution of CGI program from anywhere